# Is it possible to have url redirection inside when using graphene graphql?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, sanic

I'm currently using sanic-graphql, but I can't seem to be able to run an URL redirection at all.

```
from sanic import response

class CreateSample( Mutation ):
    class Arguments:
        input = SampleInputType()

    Output = SampleSchema

    async def mutate( self, info, input ):
        return response.redirect( 'https://www.google.com' )
```

But it seems like the logic of the library is to always try to return the return value wrapped inside the Output type.

Is there any way for me to trigger a normal URL redirection?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you showed desribes the GraphQL mutation.
It has nothing to do with user interaction.

```
class CreateSample( Mutation ): # <-- Mutation name
    class Arguments:
        input = SampleInputType()  # <-- Mutation takes one argument

    Output = SampleSchema # <-- Mutation returns object with type SampleSchema

    async def mutate( self, info, input ):
        result = do_something()
        return CreateSample(Output=result) # <-- Mutation must return self type
```

You can call mutations only with some kind of GraphQL client like Apollo client or Graphiql. So returning response.redirect does not make scenes.

You can return response.redirect() only inside sanic route. Something like -

```
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def index(request, path):
    """Catch all requests"""
    return response.redirect( 'https://www.google.com' )
```